# Exchange EWS get BCC Recipients

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, bcc

I am using EWS to create a `StreamingSubscription` on an inbox.  It is listening for the `NewMail` event.  I am able to pull the From Address, Subject, Body, To Address, CC Address but not the BCC Address.  Is there any way to see this list?

CODE:

```
static void OnEvent(object sender, NotificationEventArgs args)
{
    String from = null;
    String subject = null;
    String body = null;
    String to = null;

    StreamingSubscription subscription = args.Subscription;

    // Loop Through All Item-Related Events
    foreach (NotificationEvent notification in args.Events)
    {
        ItemEvent item = (ItemEvent)notification;

        PropertySet propertySet = new PropertySet(ItemSchema.UniqueBody);
        propertySet.RequestedBodyType = BodyType.Text;
        propertySet.BasePropertySet = BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties;

        // Parse Email
        EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.Bind(service, item.ItemId, propertySet);
        from = message.From.Address;
        subject = message.Subject;
        body = message.Body.Text;

        if (message.ToRecipients.Count > 0)
        {
            to = message.ToRecipients[0].Address;
            body += "\n TO FIELD";
        }
        else if (message.CcRecipients.Count > 0)
        {
            to = message.CcRecipients[0].Address;
            body += "\n CC FIELD";
        }
/************** Does not work! BccRecipients is always empty *****************/
        else if (message.BccRecipients.Count > 0)
        {
            to = message.BccRecipients[0].Address;
            body += "\n BCC FIELD";
        }

 /************* REST OF CODE ************************/
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would kind of defeat the point of a blind-carbon-copy.  I dont believe it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the Journaling feature of Exchange.  This uses something called "Envelope Journaling" which includes BCC information for messages within the Exchange environment.

For everything that comes from external sources (gmail) no BCC information is available.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:
http://gsexdev.blogspot.com/2011/06/processing-bccs-in-exchange-transport.html